# Reduced sqlite query speed on virtual table following library upgrade

Tags: c++, sqlite

I recently upgraded my sqlite3 library from version 3.8.7.1 to version 3.32.3, and noticed that the speed of a basic select query on a dataset of approx. 50,000 rows was about 70% slower following the upgrade. The client software works by creating a virtual table (via *sqlite3_exec()*) and then a text editor interface allows a user to execute a sql query. I was testing the upgrade with a query along the lines of:

```
Select * from SomeTable Where SomeFloatField > 0.99
```

This sql string is turned into a *sqlite3_stmt* using *sqlite3_prepare_v2()*
and then the query is executed by continually applying *sqlite3_step()* until it returns *SQLITE_DONE*.

I could include code snippets but that really wont tell you much more than I’ve explained above. It’s a fairly standard implementation of the API as far as I can tell.
But I’m trying to work out why the upgraded library is so much slower for an otherwise identical scenario. I was expecting the upgrade to be a little faster as a result of small optimizations over the years. So I can only assume I’ve overlooked some other changes I needed to make as a result of the upgrade.
I’ve identified the sqlite3_step() function as the bottleneck by putting timers into the code, but I don’t know why it would be slower and would appreciate suggestions on where to look.
For what it’s worth this is a c++ project in visual studio 2019.

Comment: Have you created an index on SomeFloatField? sqlite3 could change floating/decimal numbers precision in its updates.

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without seeing the implementation of the virtual table. Maybe something with the `xBestIndex` function?

Comment: The point is, with no code changes, an older version goes a lot faster than new latest. Unfortunately, some years ago I saw the same results with my team, and at that time we decided to not upgrade because it was not a free upgrade, to keep the same performance there are some tweaks to perform.